# xcode 6 beta 6 tab bar + navigation controller annoying log message

Tags: logging, console, swift, xcode6

I have a sample bare bone application with a view controller embedded in navigation controller, which in turn is embedded in tab bar controller. Every time I run the application there is a console output:

```
2014-08-20 23:39:44.735 SwiftTest[2341:96159] 17545849:_UIScreenEdgePanRecognizerEdgeSettings.edgeRegionSize=13.000000
```

If the navigation controller is removed the message disappears.

Is there any way to stop that message being shown?
It seams pretty harmless but it is annoying as I have to close the console window after each run of my real application.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I have same problem with Objective C in Xcode 6 beta 6.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug.  [Here is the link](http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2014/Aug/msg00030.html).